# Counterexample, where every projective representation can be lifted to a linear representation, but $H^{2}(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times}) \neq \{e\}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I am currently learning about projective representations and I have seen a proof that if $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times})=\{e\}$, then every projective representation can be lifted to a linear representation. However, I have not found anywhere that this statement would be an iff. I am trying to find a counterexample, for which it holds that every projective representation can be lifted to a linear representation, but $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times}) \neq \{e\}$. Does  anyone have a hint in mind, or a reference?

I know that projective reps. are in 1-1 correnspondence with linear reps of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ extensions, but I don't know how this helps in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $H^2(G,{\mathbb C}^\times)$ is the Schur Multiplier $M(G)$ of $G$, and $G$ has a Schur Cover $H$ with a subgroup $M \le Z(H) \cap [H,H]$ of $H$ with $M \cong M(G)$ and $H/M \cong G$.

If $M(G)$ is nontirivial, then $H$ has an irreducible complex representation $\rho$ with $M \not\le \ker \rho$, and then the projective representation $\bar{\rho}$ of $G$ induced by $\rho$ does not lift to an ordinary representation of $G$.

Comment: Is it then true that $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$ is in bijective correspondence with $\text{ProjRep}$, where $\text{ProjRep}:=\{\theta:G \to \text{PGL}(V)| \theta \; \; \text{is a group homomorphism} \}?$ Given a projective representation $\theta \in \text{ProjRep}$, we can associate to it a cohomology class. But is it true that every cohomology class comes from a projective representation? How could one see this?

Comment: This looks wrong for a number of reasons. The set ProjRep that you have defined looks infinite. Even if you restrict to irreducible representations then (as I think you have already noted) the representations that are induced by ordinary representations of $G$ all correspond to the zero cohomology class.

Comment: This makes sense. Then how to formulate mathematically that "the second cohomology group classifies projective representations"? I certainly know that central $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ extensions are in one-to-one correspondence with $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{*})$. However, my main motivation for studying $H^2$ and central extensions is itself that I am interested in projective representations. How to relate **(possibly irreducible) projective representations** to **the second cohomology group** $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{*})$? I seem not to find an answer for this in the books/articles I am learning from.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4677059/precise-relation-between-group-cohomology-and-projective-representations -  I created a concrete post about this question, not to prolong the comment section too much.

Comment: I believe the main theorem says that there is a one-one correspondence between the equivalence classes of irreducible projective representations of $G$ and the equivalence classes of irreducible ordinary representations of $H$. Here $H$ can be any Schur Cover of $G$ - it is not always uniquely determined by $G$. For example $D_8$ and $Q_8$ are both Schur Covers of the Klein 4-group.