# Precise relation between group cohomology and projective representations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4676926/projective-representations-and-group-cohomology/4676937?noredirect=1#comment9887870_4676937) and in a comment of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4676601/counterexample-where-every-projective-representation-can-be-lifted-to-a-linear/4676803?noredirect=1#comment9888131_4676803) it has been clarified that there is no bijection between the set of projective representations
\begin{equation}
\text{ProjRep}:=\{\theta:G \to \text{PGL}(V)| \theta \; \; \text{is a group homomorphism} \}.
\end{equation}
and the second cohomology group $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$. I am aware that the there is a bijection between $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$ and equivalence classes of $C^{\times}$ central extensions of $G$. However, my main motivation for studying group cohomology and central extensions is that I am interested in projective representations. In which preicse manner can one relate (possibly irreducible) projective representations and $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$?

Comment: Have you read the chapter on this topic in Isaacs' book on character theory? I recall it being described at least to some extend there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a exact sequence $1\to\mathbb C^\times\to\mathrm{GL}(V)\to\mathrm{PGL}(V)\to 1$ with trivial $G$-action, which gives rise to an exact sequence (of groups/pointed sets)
$$H^1(G,\mathbb C^\times)\to H^1(G,\mathrm{GL}(V))\to H^1(G,\mathrm{PGL}(V))\to H^2(G,\mathbb C^\times).$$
Here, $H^1(G,H)=\hom(G,H)$ when the $G$-action on $H$ is trivial. Thus, we obtain a map $\hom(G,\mathrm{PGL}(V))\to H^2(G,\mathbb C^\times)$. Although the exact sequence already tells you what the kernel is, the cokernel is unclear, since "$H^2(G,\mathrm{GL}(V))$" is not well-defined; nonabelian group cohomology is only defined for $H^0$ and $H^1$.

Comment: how does the last bit appear, or by which property is this induced? What does this sequence tell me, does it tell me that there's a surjection of the group of characters into H^2(G,C^{x})?

Comment: The statement is that there exists a map $\hom(G,\mathrm{PGL}(V))\to H^2(G,\mathbb C^\times)$, such that a homomorphism gets sent to $1$ if and only if it lifts to a representation $G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$. The last remark is that nothing concrete can be said about the image of this map; you would expect it to be described as $H^2(G,\mathrm{GL}(V))$, but such an object does not exist.